# Multiple global IPv6 prefixes

Tags: networking, routing, ipv6, radvd

I'm planning an IPv6 mesh-network with multiple gateways (routers to the internet). The connection between the gateways is not that great. The plan is that every gateway should announce two prefixes:

One "global", like 2001:DB8:1::/64,

and one only for it's location, like 2001:DB8:2:{0000-ffff}::/64.

The clients inside the mesh network should choose the later one for outgoing connections to the Internet (using the nearest gateway and avoid asynchronous traffic), but should be reachable from the internet trough 2001:DB8:1::/64, which is globally routed via anycast to all gateways.

Would this setup work, if I announce both prefixes with different RA-DefaultPreference-Values from the Gateway? Has anybody experience with an setup like that, using multiple global prefixes?